# mysql to PDO what is wrong with this query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found this script and it is really useful for me, but it is pretty old. I am using PDO in my project and I wanted to change this script's database to PDO. I have been struggling with this query for a really long time and I could not make any progress.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT facebook_posts.p_id,
facebook_posts.userid,
facebook_posts.type,
facebook_posts.title,
facebook_posts.url,
facebook_posts.description,
facebook_posts.cur_image,
facebook_posts.likes,
facebook_posts.post_type,
facebook_posts.posted_by,
facebook_posts.post,
member.*, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - facebook_posts.date_created AS TimeSpent,
facebook_posts.date_created 
FROM facebook_posts, member 
where facebook_posts.userid=".$posted_on." 
and facebook_posts.posted_by=".$user_id." 
and member.member_id =facebook_posts.userid 
order by facebook_posts.p_id desc limit 1 "
);
```

I have tried to separate into 2 query, I have tried to use UNION and finally I've written:

```
$query1 =  $database->connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT facebook_posts.p_id,
facebook_posts.userid, 
facebook_posts.type, 
facebook_posts.title, 
facebook_posts.url, 
facebook_posts.description, 
facebook_posts.cur_image, 
facebook_posts.likes, 
facebook_posts.post_type, 
facebook_posts.posted_by, 
facebook_posts.post, 
member.*,  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - facebook_posts.date_created AS TimeSpent, 
facebook_posts.date_created 
FROM facebook_posts, member 
WHERE facebook_posts.userid = :posted_on 
AND facebook_posts.posted_by = :user_id 
AND member.member_id = :member_id 
ORDER BY facebook_posts.p_id DESC LIMIT 1 ");

$query1->bindValue(':posted_on', $posted_on , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query1->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query1->bindValue(':member_id', $posted_on, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $query1->execute();
```

but it didn't work. could you tell me what is wrong with my method? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When in development, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: why don't you leave `and member.member_id =facebook_posts.userid ` line alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don't need to pass the below parameter at all.

```
$query1->bindValue(':member_id', $posted_on, PDO::PARAM_STR); //<-- Remove this whole line
```

Modify your query like this

```
$query1 =  $database->connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT facebook_posts.p_id,
facebook_posts.userid, 
facebook_posts.type, 
facebook_posts.title, 
facebook_posts.url, 
facebook_posts.description, 
facebook_posts.cur_image, 
facebook_posts.likes, 
facebook_posts.post_type, 
facebook_posts.posted_by, 
facebook_posts.post, 
member.*,  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - facebook_posts.date_created AS TimeSpent, 
facebook_posts.date_created 
FROM facebook_posts, member 
WHERE facebook_posts.userid = :posted_on 
AND facebook_posts.posted_by = :user_id 
AND member.member_id = facebook_posts.userid   //<---- Do this 
ORDER BY facebook_posts.p_id DESC LIMIT 1 ");
```

Comment: actually in the original code it says "member.member_id =facebook_posts.userid" but i don't know how to make this binding in PDO. facebook_posts is the name of the other table.